# Block a Server from reaching a machine

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a Windows 2003 server that I want to block from accessing a specific IP address. I want to control this from the Server. because I control the machine. The traffic is http traffic (webservice call). It uses a non-standard port, so IP address+ Port combination would also work.

Background:
I have a development enviornment that for some reason is ignoring host file enteries under some circumstances. These host files point the enviornment at services in another Dev enviornment. Wne th host files are ignored, dev is talking to production. This is not my question, rather the motivation for this inquiry.

I want is a failsafe to ensure dev will error instead of happily engaging in transactions with production. I control the dev server, I do not control the firewalls or the target production machine.

Comment: Might be worth fixing the bigger problems of an ignored hosts file and the production server accepting stuff from dev.

Comment: @ceejayoz I do need to address the larger issue, and I am working on this. I have no intention of leaving this problem as is. 

However, While I test and narrow down the problem, put together a coherent problem statement to owners of the firewall, I need to be sure my testing does not hit production.

The information I have on this problem is vauge, and I would not pose the problem here, or to sysadmins in it's current state.
Maybe the downvote is yours? Maybe you can you re-consider?

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, sorry. I'll counteract it, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an outbound rule to your firewall specifying IP and port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are we talking about on the Firewall on the server itself? I cannot locate these settings. The settings in  Control Pannel >> Windows Firewall.

Comment: I've not got a 2003 server to hand but they settings are usually inside the Server Manager application and look like this; http://www.windowsecurity.com/img/upl/image0021211893093934.jpg

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but I've become so used to server 2008 that I'd forgotten that 2003 didn't have outbound rules - sorry about that. That said you CAN use 'IPSec' to do this but it's far more complex to do.

Comment: Thanks @Chopper3 I'll look into the posiblity of using IPSec. Thanks for confirming that windows 2003 does not support this natively.